# React webpart OnClick event fail to call a module function

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, typescript, module

I am working on a React spfx webpart. I inserted below code in my tsx file:

```
<a href="#" className={ styles.button } onClick={ ()=> alert('greeting!') }  >
                <span className={ styles.label }>Greeting</span>
              </a>
```

In my test, the "Greeting" button show up and prompt message correctly when press.

Then I added a file "my-script.ts". The content as below:

```
export function Greeting()
{
        alert("Greeting in module!");
}
```

Then in my tsx file, I imported above module:

```
import * as MyScript from '../my-script';
```

and amended the button code as below:

```
<a href="#" className={ styles.button } onClick={ ()=> MyScript.Greeting }  >
                <span className={ styles.label }>Greeting</span>
              </a>
```

There is no error during compile. However when I press the button nothing happen. In the console there is no error. It is just not triggering anything.

May I know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make it a function call.
This setup works for me.

MyFunction.ts

```
export function Greet(){
    alert('greet');
}
```

import in tsx

```
import * as MyFunction  from './MyFunction'; //any path where you ts script is located.
```

button click

```
 <button onClick={()=>MyFunction.Greet()}>click me</button>
```

Comment: What's the different with my version?

Comment: the way you are invoking the function. also better to use a button control than a link control

Answer (score 1):

You could use the code like this ：

```
<a href="#" className={ styles.button } onClick={  MyScript.Greeting }  >
                <span className={ styles.label }>Greeting</span>
              </a>
```

Official document:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html